# Cannot upload files from S3 Development Bucket in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When running my rails app in development mode from Nitrous.io, I cannot access my development bucket which I set up on AWS S3.  The upload button opens my personal computer, from where I don't want to load files.  (even when I try to load files from my computer, I get a long error message stating "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method"

I think I don't have AWS S3 configured properly.

Currently, I have one IAM user, which I've assigned to AdministratorAccess  Also, I am using the proper AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in my application.yml file.  In fog.rb I have it read from the enviroment.

I should add too that I currently enrolled in a web development apprenticeship program.

Sorry for not showing my files

Here's my application.yml with the sensitive data taken out:

```
SENDGRID_PASSWORD: alphanumberic
SENDGRID_USERNAME: -------@heroku.com
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: alphanumeric
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: alphanumeric
development:
  AWS_BUCKET: vmanamino-bloccit-development
production:
  AWS_BUCKET: vmanamino-bloccit-production

development:
  secret_key_base: alphanumeric
test:
  secret_key_base: alphanumeric
```

Here's my fog.rb file which reads the values from the environment

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:  'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],       
  }

  config.fog_directory = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']

  config.fog_public = true
end
```

Comment: Can you double check the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to ensure it does not have any trailing or leading spaces?

Comment: You've got to show us how you're doing some of these things - it's just guesswork otherwise

Comment: @AlexS.I checked for trailing spaces using the cursor, and found none.  However, the leading space exists between the colon and the start of the alpha numeric AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Comment: @FrederickCheung Sorry about that.  I added file content above.

Comment: @FrederickCheung the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY belong to a IAM user I created in AWS.  This IAM user I assigned to AdminstrativeAccess

Comment: Does anyone know how i could check whether my AWS credentials are working?  Perhaps that could help to pinpoint the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` environment variable for both the access key and the secret access key whereas the latter should of course be using `ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']`

Comment: Let me correct that and see if environment variables work in development.  I was thinking that I couldn't use those in development.

Comment: My theory seems to be correct.  I just set the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and the AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to to environment variables, and to the same error:  Excon::Errors::Forbidden in UsersController#update  Once I provide the actual values for the KEY_ID and ACCESS_KEY, then I can upload images to S3.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize I needed to enclose the KEY ID and the SECRET KEY  in quotes.  Once I did that, I got it to work.  I can upload images from my conputer to S3.  Also, I didn't understand the assignment perfectly.  I thought my app would upload images from S3.  Now, the error raised earlier makes sense.  I upload from my computer sending the image to S3.